# tkinter - Cant hide nested toplevel window

Tags: python, class, tkinter, nested, toplevel

I create an instance of TopLevel class inside another class, but can't "withdraw()" the child window
with a call from parent.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Table(tk.Toplevel):


    def __init__(self, master):

      tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master)

      self.var_new_t=tk.Toplevel(self.master)  

      self.t2=Table_2(self.var_new_t)

      #Goal is to create a child window and immediately hide it.

      self.t2.hide_me()
      #self.t2.withdraw()  ##Tried a few differnt ways 


class Table_2(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master):
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
            self.master = master
            label = tk.Label(self.master, bg='green', text='Second Table')
            label.grid()

    def hide_me(self):

        self.master.withdraw()

root = tk.Tk()

n= Table(root)

tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I tried a few other variations to no avail.

Comment: Change to `self.withdraw()` and this `self.var_new_t=tk.Toplevel(self.master)` is not required, double work. Also this `self.t2=Table_2(self.var_new_t)` have to be `self.t2=Table_2(self)` or `self.t2=Table_2(master)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating two windows. Consider this code:

`Table` is a toplevel window because it inherits from `Toplevel`. So, this line creates the `Table` window:

```
  tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
```

Then, you create *another* window when you do this:

```
  self.var_new_t=tk.Toplevel(self.master)
```

If you inherit from `Toplevel` you typically shouldn't create a second `Toplevel` inside unless you explicitly intend to create two windows.

Your code needs to look something like this:

```
class Table(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
      tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
      self.t2=Table_2(self)
      self.t2.hide_me()

class Table_2(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,master)
            self.master = master
            label = tk.Label(self, bg='green', text='Second Table')
            label.grid()

    def hide_me(self):
        self.withdraw()
```

Comment: Both answer worked, but i would like to point out that inside Table_2, you also changed: label = tk.Label(self.master, bg='green', text='Second Table') to label = tk.Label(self, bg='green', text='Second Table')......Calling the method this way also resulted in it not withdrawing.

Comment: @DannyW: `tk.Label(self.master)` puts the label in the first Toplevel. I was assuming you wanted it inside `Table2`.

Comment: You are correct (2nd table). I just realized that yes, placing the label on master table, I was thinking it was table_2, when it was just showing the "Second Table" label on master table. ---Causing me to believe withdraw was not working this whole time!